# Can / should I remove special CSS comments in minified stylesheet?

Tags: css, comments

This is about special comments on top of most of vendor CSS. I mean, this kind of comments :

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT - (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
```

I was wondering a few things about them :

1. Can I legally remove them from a minified stylesheet?
2. If yes, should I remove them? Why?
3. If not, is there a way to merge all special comments to place them at top of a concatenated and minified file generated with gulp or grunt?

Comment: 1. [No](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57364/53438), because it is a condition of the MIT license to keep this copyright notice *in all copies or substantial portions of the Software*. This really is the only condition of the MIT license to get a piece of software for free, so it is just fair to not remove the comment (besides all legal aspects).

Comment: @Marvin What about the question no. 3, that sounds like a fair point?

Comment: To be clear, I added a special page on my website, I think that's fair for the developers.